# How to effectively fix a leak in an inflatable mattress that is leaking on a seam?

Tags: bedroom, repair, furniture

It's not uncommon for air mattresses to leak along a seam.  When this happens, repair kits are pretty much useless.

What is an effective way to repair a leak in an air mattress when the leak is along a seam?

If curing is involved, the curing will ideally take no more than a couple hours.

Also, ideally, the mattress would not need to be deflated for the repair to proceed.  But that's just an ideal preference, and not a requirement for this QA.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use low viscosity glue. In Germany we have "Schweisskleber" which translates to  welding glue. But it has nothing to do with welding. It's just a low viscosity glue. It comes in these cans [image: welding glue]

Deflate the mattress and use a brush to generously apply the glue along the seam. Let it dry and repeat. Do at least 2 layers, recommend 3.

There are different types of this glue for different materials.

Comment: Thanks Rubus.  How long does that glue usually take to dry per layer?

Comment: If I remember correctly about 24h..But I guess there are differences

Comment: Thanks.  The amount of time required is not ideal for repairing a mattress, but I still sincerely appreciate your answer.  Your answer also uses a key phrase I hadn't considered: "low viscosity"... thanks for mentioning it.